# How to make a table in the question?

Tags: bug, questions, math-se, tables

I want to ask a question in mathematics, in which I want to add a table with some alpha numeric values. How can I do this? Can I enter an image in the text?

Comment: As for images: you need 10 reputation to be able to add images to your post. If you don't have that, just upload the image somewhere and add a link in your post. (On the Maths sites, use the MathJax table options listed in the linked question rather than an image.)